# Detecting if EditText contains only a decimal point

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

```xml
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtxt1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:maxLength="15"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittxt"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_height="50dp" />
```

I have a unit converter app. Everything works fine, but the only problem I have is if the user enter only a decimal point `"."` in the EditText and tries to convert one parameter to another, the app crashes!

How could I detect if only a decimal point is entered (ie. without the numbers; like `"."` is entered instead of `"3.03"` or `".3"`).

I used the code below to detect if the EditText is empty when the user is trying to convert from one parameter to another, but it doesn't work for decimal point.

```
if (cel1.matches(""))
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter the content!",
                                                         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: `if (cel1.equals("") || cel1.equals("."))` ?

Comment: Please take a look at my answer and give me some feedback on what you want. If it works for you, please accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking for *just* a decimal point:

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtxt1);
if (et.getText().toString().equals("."))
{
    // run your code here
}
```

---

Using your code:

```
if (cel1.equals("") || cel1.equals("."))
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter the content!",
                                                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Perhaps you want to change `cel1.equals(".")` to `cel1.trim().equals(".")` just to make sure the condition works even if there are blank spaces in there as well. I'm not sure if you allow spaces in the first place, though.

Comment: @AshwinShirva I did that right away. I was the first one lol.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if only a decimal point is in the EditText:

//Get text from the EditText and check if it's a dot.

```
if (editText.getText().toString().equals("."))
{
    //display error message
}
```

Comment: This won't even compile.

Comment: and why wont it compile?

Comment: You need to wrap the if condition in quotes. `if editText.getText().toString().equals(".")` would need to be `if (editText.getText().toString().equals("."))`. I suggest creating a "TestCode" workspace in Android/Java to try out code before you post it.

Comment: ah you're right, its just a habit lol :P Think everyone should know this if they're trying to code ^^ my bad

Answer (score 0):

You can check this:

As u asked about `without the numbers,like "." is entered instead of "3.03" or ".3"`

```
EditText edittext1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtxt1)
String cel1= edittext1.getText().toString();

if (cel1.trim().length()!=0 && cel1.startsWith("[.]");)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong content here, please Try again!!",
                                                         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: He means entering just a decimal, *not* a decimal and a number. So your code won't work for him.